# How to kill sidekiq job in Rails 4 with ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Let's say we have test job:

```
class TestJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(video)
    video.process
  end
end
```

After it we run `bundle exec sidekiq start`

And run in new terminal window in rails console

`Video.first.pending!; TestJob.perform_later(Video.first)`

Job is running, ffmpeg is on background, everything is fine, but according to [official sidekiq wiki docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API) I try:

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
Sidekiq::Queue.new
=> #<Sidekiq::Queue:0x00000006406978 @name="default", @rname="queue:default">

Sidekiq::Queue.new.each {|job| puts job}
=> nil
Sidekiq::Queue.new.size
=> 0
ss = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
=> #<Sidekiq::ScheduledSet:0x000000064a4330 @_size=0, @name="schedule">
ss.size
=> 0
```

Why there is no jobs? The job is running successfully ( I see it also in first window where sidekiq starts, but I can't see and delete  it in rails console )

I am using Ubuntu 14 if it helps

With best regards, Ruslan.

**UPD:**
It looks that
`ps = Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new; ps.each(&:quiet!)`
works
, but it doesn't stop my ffmpeg process this part of code internally in process:

```
cmd = "ffmpeg -i #{input_file.shellescape} #{options} -threads 0 -y #{self.path + outfile}"
pid = spawn(cmd, :out => output_file, :err => output_file)
Process.wait(pid)
```

How to stop it?

Comment: No, the job is running 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a job is processing, it's not enqueued anymore.

Comment: Ou, @Mike Perkham, thanks a lot , but how to find processing job ?

Comment: Sidekiq does not provide any way to stop a job as it cannot be done safely.  You'd have to implement something in your job which periodically checks if it should stop.

Answer (score 0):

I use sidekiq web UI and various queues for my jobs.  If I realize that particular job is failing I can clear out the queue of subsequent jobs of the same class.